# Flex/Bison: How do I have this "SELECT 123 + ,"?

Tags: c, bison, flex-lexer

I have created a very simple SQL parser, but during fuzz testing I've come across this situation:

```
SELECT   123     +      ,
K_SELECT INTEGER T_PLUS T_COMMA
```

Of course this is a syntax error, but I don't know how to "catch" it.

How does it decide between the "next_column_expression came too early" and "binary_expression didn't finish". I've worked with ANTLR3 a fair bit on Java project. But this is totally different.

Here is the skeleton parser rules:

```
/* be more versbose about error messages */
%error-verbose

/* keywords */
%token K_CREATE
%token K_FROM
%token K_INTEGER
%token K_SELECT
%token K_TABLE
%token K_TEXT
%token K_WHERE
%token K_VALUES
%token K_INSERT
%token K_INTO

/* variable tokens */
%token IDENTIFIER
%token INTEGER

/* fixed tokens */
%token T_ASTERISK
%token T_PLUS
%token T_EQUALS
%token T_END ";"
%token T_COMMA
%token T_BRACKET_OPEN
%token T_BRACKET_CLOSE

%token END 0 "end of file"

%%

input:
    statement {
    }
    END
;

statement:
    select_statement {
    }
    |
    create_table_statement {
    }
    |
    insert_statement {
    }
;

keyword:
    K_CREATE | K_FROM | K_INTEGER | K_SELECT | K_TABLE | K_TEXT | K_WHERE | K_VALUES | K_INSERT | K_INTO
;

table_name:
    error {
        // "Expected table name"
    }
    |
    keyword {
        // "You cannot use a keyword for a table name."
    }
    |
    IDENTIFIER {
    }
;

select_statement:
    K_SELECT column_expression_list {
        // "Expected FROM after column list."
    }
    error
    |
    K_SELECT error {
        // "Expected column list after SELECT."
    }
    |
    K_SELECT column_expression_list {
    }
    K_FROM table_name {
    }
;

column_expression_list:
    column_expression {
    }
    next_column_expression
;

column_expression:
    T_ASTERISK {
    }
    |
    expression {
    }
;

next_column_expression:
    |
    T_COMMA column_expression {
    }
    next_column_expression
;

binary_expression:
    value {
    }
    operator {
    }
    value {
    }
;

expression:
    value
    |
    binary_expression
;

operator:
    T_PLUS {
    }
    |
    T_EQUALS {
    }
;

value:
    INTEGER {
    }
    |
    IDENTIFIER {
    }
;

%%
```

Comment: Pick one or the other, and go with that. As for more on Yacc error handling, why not read the first hit on Google: http://www.cs.nmsu.edu/~pfeiffer/classes/370/notes/yaccerrorhandling/index.php?currentsem=s10

Comment: I'd rather it decide the binary_expression is not properly formed and jump into some exit code. So the ',' will only ever get peaked at, it won't try to read the next column_expression ... ?

Comment: Yacc has a special "error" production that you can insert at strategic points (e.g. before a semicolon) so that it becomes possible to resume parsing at the next statement. Check the documentation for details.

Comment: Yes I know about "error" you can see im already using it to handle some situation. My question is what syntax do I need to use to recover from a premature binary_expression? I think bison only reads one token ahead so how I expect it should work doesn't

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to understand LR (shift-reduce) parsing, and you need to understand how yacc recovers from errors, using error rules in the grammar.  The former is a big question, and there are a number of books that cover the theory and practice PDAs and shift-reduce parsing (The classics, [Hopcroft & Ullman](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201441241) and [Aho, Sethi & Ullman](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201100886) are complete if rather dense).

Once you understand shift-reduce parsing, yacc error recovery is reasonably straight-forward.  Basically, whenever it gets into a state where it can't shift or reduce on the current tokens, it takes a simple sequence of steps to try to recover:

1. It pops states until it gets to one that can shift the special `error` token.  This might be zero pops if the current state can shift `error`.
2. It shifts the error token, and then does any default reductions in the target state.
3. It throws away input tokens until it finds one that can be handled in the current state.  As with the state dropping, that might be zero discards if the state after shifting `error` can handle the next token.

and that's it.

So If we look at what happens with your current grammar and example erroneous input we that it:

1. shifts the `SELECT` token going into a state `select_statement: K_SELECT ...`
2. shifts the `123` token, reduces it to a `value` and shifts to a state `*expr: value ...`
3. shifts the `+` token, reduces it to an `operator` and shifts to a state `binary_expression: value operator ...`
4. Sees the token `,` and can't shift or reduce in the current state, so issues a syntax error.
5. Pops states looking for one that can handle `error`.  The top two states (from 3 and 2 above) can't so are discarded.  The next state can, so we end up in a state `select_statement: K_SELECT error`
6. That is a default reduction state, so it is reduced to `select_statement` which is then reduced to `statement` which shifts to a state `input: statement END`
7. It starts throwing away input tokens until it finds one the current state can handle, which is only `END`.  So it throws aways everything until it gets to `END` or eof.

Now your question seems to be, "How do I do something different?"

If you want a 'binary expression not complete' recovery, you could add a rule like:

```
binary_expression: value error
```

This would end up as part of the `*expr: value` state above, so error recovery would stop popping there and shift the error token, ending up in a state that can shift the `,` token.

Whenever you're trying to untangle the states in a large grammar and understand what error recovery will do, it helps tremendously to run yacc/bison with the -v flags to produce a `.output` file with all the states in it.

Comment: Thank you, that was really helpful. I sort of understand what you mean but I'll have to research it further.I managed to fix my problem by reducing the binary_expression into several child rules with error conditions where I need them, so "binary_expression: value binary_expression_op binary_expression_right" no leaks, no crashes and it's doing everything it should :)